# how do i get addressbook of yahoo using YDN

Tags: php, javascript, yahoo, yahoo-api

i wanted to get all contacts from yahoo account using YDN.
because i want to make send invitation application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/):

```
select * from social.contacts where guid=me;
```

Comment: this is not giving all my contacts